# UIWebView load local video data

Tags: objective-c, ios, video, uiwebview

I am trying to load a Video in UIWebView. Video is stored in local file system. Here is the code snippet I am using for loading the video.

```
{
   NSString* filePAth = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sample_iPod" ofType:@"m4v"];
   NSLog(@"%@",filePAth);
   NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePAth];
   [_webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"video/x-m4v" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
}
```

This is the error I get in console:

> Error in Webview loading: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=204
>   "Plug-in handled load" UserInfo=0x1f8b3c70
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=applewebdata://3F0047AD-E6CF-4EAD-A4C3-DA6E1C0BD603,
>   WebKitErrorMIMETypeKey=video/x-m4v,
>   NSErrorFailingURLKey=applewebdata://3F0047AD-E6CF-4EAD-A4C3-DA6E1C0BD603,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=Plug-in handled load}

However, The same code works for loading all other file type for eg: PNG, DOC et.c.

Please help...!!!

Comment: Why would you want to use WebView for playing a video file located on the device ? MPMoviePlayerViewController is much simpler, uses less memory and is made to lay this. Remember that WebView is not Safari.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to load the video in UIWebview because I am loading different file formats in that view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should load local videos and other videos whenever possible with `MPMoviePlayerController` - ([Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) - If playing the video is all you need and want and you are developing a native app.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to load the video in UIWebview because I am loading different file formats in that view.

Comment: You could have a hidden MPMoviePlayerController of the same size, and if the user selects a video, you show the player and play, if the user selects an image, you stop the video and hide it. I did this in the WGSN app - https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/wgsn-365/id550174392?mt=8 - check out screenshot #3 it's a content viewer with pdf/images as viable via webview and video via a MPMoviePlayerController laid on top

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your data to base64 string and use HTML capability of Safari with `video` tag

```
NSString *base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" \
                     <div style=\"height:100%%;\"> \
                     <p style=\"position: absolute; top: 50%%; left: 50%%; transform: translate(-50%%, -50%%)\"> \
                     <video controls> \
                     <source type=\"%@\" src=\"data:%@;base64,%@\"> \
                     </video></p></div>", contentType, contentType, base64String];

[webView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];
```

Here `data` is your raw video data, `contentType` is contentType string.

Comment: I'm having memory problems in this way

Comment: @BryanPosas, it is unavoidable for very large video, because I load all file data into memory. But it seems that it is the only way to handle video data in webView.

Comment: We have the same circumstance but for me even just 37 mb would send it crashing