# Play local video file in UIwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I can't play local video file in UIWebview. Here is my code anything wrong? or Apple can't allow to play local video file in UIWebview.

```
NSString *webViewString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<!doctypehtml><html><head><title>SimpleMoviePlayer</title></head><body><videosrc=\"%@\">controls autoplay height=\"270\">
 width=\"1000\"></video></body></html>",pathOftheLocalFile];

UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame+(i*20), 0, 300, height)];

webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webview.delegate = self;
[webview loadHTMLString:webViewString baseURL:nil];
[previewScrollView addSubview:webview];
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/4874198/1679187 OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861503/uiwebview-load-local-video-data

Comment: Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836595/playing-a-local-video-in-a-uiwebview

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to play video from local in UIWebview. I already referred all those links that are not working for me.

Comment: I think am asking correctly.@andrew Barber.

Comment: NO idea why this question was closed.  There's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<body>
<div>
<embed src="yourVideoName.mov" Pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" width="90%"   height="166px" CONTROLLER="true" LOOP="false" AUTOPLAY="false" name="IBM Video"></embed>
</div>
</body></html>"];

UIWebView *webview = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame+(i*20), 0, 300,   height)];
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
webview.delegate = self;
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
[previewScrollView addSubview:webview];
```

Comment: No, it can't work for me. @SGRKDL

Comment: If the video is part of the app bundle then you can load into the web view but if its in documents directory you can't load it here is the [link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-E04kqghLhYk/V7W1aWfKtTI/AAAAAAAAGUo/xavby-jUx7oIP7nGHXa42-f1GeIq5LaWACL0B/w1500-h162-no/Console.png)

Comment: If the video is part of the app bundle then you can load into the web view but if its in documents directory you can't load it here is the [link](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-E04kqghLhYk/V7W1aWfKtTI/AAAAAAAAGUo/xavby-jUx7oIP7nGHXa42-f1GeIq5LaWACL0B/w1500-h162-no/Console.png).Here is an alternative [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39032697/730807)