# How to embed multiple videos in swift?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, uikit, avfoundation, uipagecontrol

How to create array of multiple mp4 or mov files in swift. I was able to display the single video in uiwebview. I have pagecontrol to display some text  but I need to display different videos same like texts. When the page control starts it should display next video. Here is the code for first view controller and page view controller.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    //var pageImages:NSArray!
    var ouotes: NSArray!
    var video: NSArray!
    var pageViewController:UIPageViewController!

    @IBOutlet weak var GenerateNumbers: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        video = ["2.mov", "1.mov", "4.mov"]
        ouotes =  ["sometext" ]

        // NSArray(objects:"ap", "bg", "gfb")
        /*  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size)
        UIImage(named: "money")?.draw(in: self.view.bounds)

        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: image)*/

        self.pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyPageViewController") as! UIPageViewController

        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        let initialContenViewController = self.pageTutorialAtIndex(0) as ContentHolder

        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([initialContenViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height-100)

        self.addChildViewController(self.pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(self.pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func pageTutorialAtIndex(_ index: Int) -> ContentHolder {

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentHolder") as! ContentHolder

        pageContentViewController.imageFileName = ouotes[index] as! String
        pageContentViewController.videoFileName = video [index] as! String
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController

    }


    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let viewController = viewController as! ContentHolder
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int

        if (index == 0 || index == NSNotFound) {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1

        return self.pageTutorialAtIndex(index)
    }

    public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let viewController = viewController as! ContentHolder
        var index = viewController.pageIndex as Int

        if ((index == NSNotFound)) {
            return nil
        }

        index += 1

        if (index == ouotes.count) {
            return nil
        }

        if (index == video.count) {
            return nil
        }
        return self.pageTutorialAtIndex(index)
    }



    public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {   
        return ouotes.count
    }

    public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int{

        return 0
    }
}
```

And for the pagecontrol view where texts and videos should be displayed

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ContentHolder: UIViewController {

    var imageFileName: String!
    var videoFileName: String!
    var pageIndex:Int!

    @IBOutlet weak var EuroScrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var VideoView: UIWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // let fileURL = NSURL (fileURLWithPath: "/Users/nafu/Desktop/2.mov")

        VideoView.loadHTMLString("<iframe width = \"\(self.VideoView.frame.width) \" height =\"\(self.VideoView.frame.height)\" src = \"\(videoFileName)\"> </iframe>", baseURL: nil)

       myLabel.text = imageFileName
       myLabel.numberOfLines = 0
       myLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
       myLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 15.0)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried already? please provide as much detail as you can, some code, better explanation will get better answer

Comment: now I have edited my question

Comment: What are the video URL's or where are the videos stored?

Comment: Videos are .mov files which are stored locally in computer and  I have imported them to my xcode project.

Comment: Have you tried these other answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063276/how-to-load-local-html-file-into-uiwebview and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24551251/play-local-video-file-in-uiwebview ? You can load a video if it is part of the app bundle. Make sure in your build rules that the videos are copied to device too

Comment: Yes I tried and did not work and Videos are in app bundle and copied to device.